# Python text-to-speech module

Tags: python, text-to-speech

Python gtts module was working on python 2.7 but an error has recently appeared.

Snapshot of the code is as follows:

```
from gtts import gTTS
#final_news is string which will be converted to speech
final_news= " I am Tina, ypur digital assistant"
tts = gTTS(text=final_news, lang='en')
tts.save("news.mp3")
```

traceback is as follows:
file "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\gtts\tts.py , line 247 in self.write_to_fp(f)
file "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\gtts \tts.py , line 187 , in write_to_fpart_tk = self.token.calculate_token(part)
file "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\gtts_token\gtts_token.py\" , line 28 , in calculate_token seed = self._get_token_key()
file "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\gtts_token\gtts_token.py\" ,line62 , in _get_token_key  a = re.search("a\\x3d(-?\d+);" ,tkk_expr.group(1)  AttributeError :'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Any clues?
Thanks

Comment: Can you post the complete traceback? It appears that the module expects `tkk_expr` to be a regex match, but that match has failed.

Comment: File "73_audio,py" , line 83 , in <module>

Comment: The comments are unsuitable for reading code/error messages, please edit them into the question, and use code formatting (Ctrl-K) to preserve formatting.

Comment: Please use code formatting (select text, press Ctrl-K), not quoting.

Comment: @tim-pietzcker screen shot attached

Comment: You were specifically asked to post code, not a screenshot. Screenshots are not a helpful way to convey terminal output. Please fix.

Comment: @mad-physicist  the  code is posted